# accessing Double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

typedef struct _WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS {

ULONG  Size;

WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfigType  Type;

union {

```
struct {
  PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR  ConfigurationDescriptor;
  PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR*  InterfaceDescriptors;
  ULONG NumInterfaceDescriptors;
} Descriptor;
struct {
  PURB  Urb;
} Urb;
struct {
  UCHAR  NumberConfiguredPipes;
  WDFUSBINTERFACE  ConfiguredUsbInterface;
} SingleInterface;
struct {
  UCHAR  NumberInterfaces;
  PWDF_USB_INTERFACE_SETTING_PAIR  Pairs;
  UCHAR  NumberOfConfiguredInterfaces;
} MultiInterface;
```

} Types;

} WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS, *PWDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS;

WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS params;

typedef struct _USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR {

UCHAR  bLength ;

UCHAR  bInterfaceClass ;

UCHAR  bInterfaceSubClass ;

} USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR ;

Able to acess NumInterfaceDescriptors via ->  params.Types.Descriptor.NumInterfaceDescriptors

**I want to acess bInterfaceClass  via  WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS .
Please note that this structure is filled by the library I have to just access it**

Comment: Why do you want the type IntDesc to be a double pointer?

typedef PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR* IntDesc;

Wouldn't it be easier just to use a single pointer? What's the benefit of another layer of indirection here?

Comment: Hey, dude... you've changed the question significantly two times now, each time *breaking previously valid answers*, and each time *breaking the layout others had fixed for you previously*. I have very little patience with people who are that careless with other people's time. -1 from me, and I won't bother to edit / answer your question again.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, this is now a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085761/accessing-a-structure-variable-double-pointer

Answer (score 6):

```
(*someIntDesc)->iInterface
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IntDesc foo;
// somehow initialize foo to actually point to (a pointer to) a valid structure
(*foo)->iInterface = 10;
```

Comment: You're right, of course. I shouldn't take linguistic shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Deference it like this

```
(*intDesc)->iInterface
```

Answer (score 1):

IntDesc is a type, not a variable.  So the first thing you need to do is create a variable of the correct type:

```
IntDesc id;
```

Next, you'll need to have it point to allocated memory.  I'm going to put everything on the stack, you may have other needs:

```
USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR usb;
PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR pusb = &usb;
id = &pusb;
```

Now that you have a valid pointer, you can go ahead an dereference it.  Since this is a double pointer, you will need to dereference it twice:

```
(*(*id)).iInterface = 10;
```

Because C defines `->` as a combination of `*` and `.`, you can express that more succinctly with:

```
(*id)->iInterface = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the name `InterfaceDescriptors`, it would appear to point to an array of pointers to the structure.  So the more idiomatic way would be:

```
InterfaceDescriptors[0]->iInterface = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite wrong

```
NODE* ptr;
k.N.iInterface = 100;
ptr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

And before accesing:

```
ptr->N1->iInterface
```

N1 should be initialized to something.