# Accessing a structure variable double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Some code:

```
typedef struct _WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS { 
ULONG Size;
WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfigType Type;
union {   
     struct {
     PUSB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR  ConfigurationDescriptor;
     PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR*  InterfaceDescriptors;
     ULONG NumInterfaceDescriptors;
     } Descriptor;

     struct {
     PURB  Urb;
     } Urb;
   } Types;
```

} WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS,*PWDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS;
     WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS params;

```
typedef struct _USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR {
UCHAR bLength ;
UCHAR bInterfaceClass ;
UCHAR bInterfaceSubClass ;
} USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR, *PUSB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR ;
```

Able to acess NumInterfaceDescriptors via -> params.Types.Descriptor.NumInterfaceDescriptors

**I want to acess bInterfaceClass via WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS .**
Please note that this structure is filled by the library I have to just access it

Comment: I have rolled this back so at least the code is legible. Please take any further edits forward from this point, and when you have done an edit, check that what you have done produces legible output!

Comment: And remember that what appears in the edit preview is NOT necessarily what appears on the final page.

Comment: @Neil: good work ... I tried a couple of times, including copying the code to an external editor and tidying it up there, but I gave up. I find it very hard to decipher still, when the union's members aren't indented. Not your fault of course, it was quite a mouthfall to begin with.

Comment: @unwind - Yeah, I can't make head nor tail of it myself :-)

Comment: @Sikandar: for our sake, pick an indent style (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and use it. If you don't know which, try whatever your IDE supports (IDEs and other programming editors should support auto-indenting).

Comment: With regards to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084077/accessing-double-pointer (and my comment to it), **please** try to proof-read your questions before submitting, and **pretty please** try not to significantly change the question once you asked it. I'd also recommend learning to walk before you run, i.e. learning how to handle structs, pointers and typedef's **before** you go into USB interface programming.

Comment: The correct terminology is "pointer to pointer."

Answer (score 2):

It *appears* that what you want is:

```
ULONG iface;

for (iface = 0; iface < params.Types.Descriptor.NumInterfaceDescriptors; iface++)
{
    do_something_with(params.Types.Descriptor.InterfaceDescriptors[iface]);
}
```

..but you should really put some more time into making your questions clear so that people don't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: InterfaceDescriptors is a double pointer pointing to structure

Comment: I can see that.  The structure definition strongly implies that it is a pointer to an array of `NumInterfaceDescriptors` pointers to structures.

Answer (score 1):

Google for WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS. The first hit leads you to the relevant MSDN page, which tells you that Types.Descriptor.InterfaceDescriptors

> contains a driver-supplied pointer to **an array of** USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR structures

and that Types.Descriptor.NumInterfaceDescriptors indeed

> contains the **number of elements** that are in the interface **array** that Types.Descriptor.InterfaceDescriptors points to.

Ergo, your "pointer to pointer" is actually an array of USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR pointers.